# Find shortest path between multiple locations c#

Tags: c#, shortest-path

I have list of location with their coordinates and also current location with lat long.
Now,i want to find shortest route according to my list of locations(lat-longs)

Just i need to sort the location according to route wise.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What code or approach have you tried? let us know first.

Comment: i didn't tried any code. i am asking which approach i should follow

Comment: You are not providing enough information. What are the possible paths? Are there straight lines between every pair of locations? Are there specific paths and their length is given in an array? I suggest you read the chapter of CLRS on graph theory and you'll master the kind of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

Just a bit of background.
It seems that you are trying to solve the "traveling salesman" problem. ie. What is the best route for a salesman to visit all of his customers (or travel to all locations).

The most famous algorithm for this is known as [Djikstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)
It is essentially the algorithm to find the shortest path between all nodes in a graph.

If you are able to represent your locations in a graph data structure, you are probably able to use Djikstras algorithm to solve your problem.

There is another problem however, that is if there are too many nodes in your graph (too many locations), then you will not be able to use this algorithm to get the shortest distance. This is because the algorithm is very time complex and the more nodes in the graph, the longer the time will take to compute the answer. If this is to be the case, you need to use other algorithms to approximate the shortest path. This is unlikely to give you the actual shortest path but it should give you a pretty good path. An algorithms for this approach is [Simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) which is quite a lot more involved as you need to fine tune certain variables for each application.